# How do I cycle through each line of a text file or string, and set it to a variable in Node Js?

Tags: node.js, arrays, string, sorting

I have a text file with names, each name is on a different line. I want to set the first line to a variable, then after 3 seconds, take the second line and set it to the same variable and so forth. Something like a for loop will probably try to be used. I am using Node Js, and can use packages and others code etc, just need a way to get this done. Additionally I can set the text files contents to a string, so if there is no way to sort through the text file I can use a string no problem. I just need a way to go through the lines and set each to a variable (const, var, etc).

Test.txt example:
Kevin
Bob
Sally
Darla
John
Kim

Then what I want to do is set line 1: Kevin to a string.
const name = Kevin;
Then 3 seconds later set it to Bob etc etc.

Thanks in advance!

Line Reader NPM Package Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/line-reader

Current Code to Set Text File Contents to a String:

```
var lineReader = require('line-reader');

lineReader.eachLine('Test.txt', function(text, last) {
  console.log(text);
//"text" is equal to the contents of the text file Test.txt
});
```

Comment: `let name = line`

Comment: Sorry that was a bad variable name. Line is equal to all the lines. I'll fix that.

Comment: Based on docs: The eachLine function reads each line of the given file. Upon each new line, the given callback function is called with two parameters: the line read and a boolean value specifying whether the line read was the last line of the file. If the callback returns false, reading will stop and the file will be closed

Comment: Perhaps it looks to you like it's only printing the file content (perhaps if you don't realize there is an automatic loop with `eachLine`?). If you `console.log("name:", text);` maybe it'll make it more obvious?

Comment: Yes it does add name to every line but it then sends line as all the line just with name in front of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `readline` internal module ([file reading example](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_example_read_file_stream_line_by_line)).

CJS variant:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

function sleep(time) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, time);
  });
}

async function processLineByLine() {
  const fileStream = fs.createReadStream('test.txt');

  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fileStream,
    crlfDelay: Infinity
  });

  for await (const line of rl) {
    console.log(line);
    await sleep(3000);
  }
}

processLineByLine();
```

ESM variant with top-level `await`:

```js
import fs from 'fs';
import readline from 'readline';

function sleep(time) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, time);
  });
}

const fileStream = fs.createReadStream('test.txt');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: fileStream,
  crlfDelay: Infinity
});

for await (const line of rl) {
  console.log(line);
  await sleep(3000);
}
```

Comment: It works fine until the setTimeout function and it gives this error. https://pastebin.com/8U7Fs8Cx Sorry if I am not allowed to use paste bins.

Comment: I am not sure how to use the imports. @vsemozhebuty

Comment: @Poetic It seems you need Node.js 16 to use promisified timers. Let me know if you cannot upgrade — I will try to make another variant.

Comment: @Poetic About using imports: https://dmitripavlutin.com/ecmascript-modules-nodejs/

Comment: @Poetic I've edited both variants to use a bit older API.

Comment: I just used Node.js 16, and it works fine thanks though! And I will definitely read up on using imports!